# Breakpoint not working inside a Handler - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

All the other breakpoints inside my class work just fine.
However, none of the breakpoints inside the `run` method. What can the issue be?

```
  private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object...args) {

            new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatService.this, "connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
                    String json = gson.toJson(user);
                    try {
                        obj = new JSONObject(json);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mSocket.emit("set-user-data", obj, user.getRole());

                    JSONArray membersJSONArray = new JSONArray();
                    membersJSONArray.put(user.getUsername());


                    JSONObject roomInfo = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        roomInfo.put("members", membersJSONArray);
                        roomInfo.put("platformInfo", user.getPlatformInfo());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mSocket.emit("set-room", roomInfo);

                }
            });


        }
    };
```

Comment: does `call` method executes at all?

Comment: @pskink Yes it does. The toast inside  flashes on the screen